# laravel sanctum Route [login] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I am trying to get the current user in my laravel vue application. And whenever I trie to get it i am getting this error:

`Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined. in file C:\Users\Moeme\Documents\School\HsLeiden\Keuzevakken\IKFRAM\sla ticketsystem\ticketsystem\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 444`

This is what I am sending in postman:

[image: this is what I send in postman]

This is what I have in my `routes\api.php`

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) { 
    return $request->user();
});
```

I really do not know why it is not working

Thanks for the help

Comment: Accept and Authorization should not be in the Params but in the Headers. Add Accept application/json to your header and add your token in the Authorization Tab. Postman has an option for Bearer in Authorization Tab, then add your token without without the "Bearer" in the field.

Answer (score 28):

Add new config at headers

```
"Accept"=>"application/json"
```

Laravel will check the configuration for "Accept", it will return the web page or html if no value is set at "Accept" by default

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error when making the request only for the postman, add this to the headers

**key**: Accept

**Value**: application/json[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Your URL incorrect. Remove "/" before query parameters.

   https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user?param1=value&param2=value - this for route '/api/user' with query params "param1" and "param2"
2. You are trying pass headers in a query parameters. Move "Accept" and "Authorization" to "Headers" tab for requests in Postman.